# No intellisense in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, intellisense

I use Microsoft Visual Studio to code in VB

This is the first time I code in C# and there is no intellisense.
Tried

> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor

and there is nothing C# related

How to fix this?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have? It's not an Express Edition is it?

Comment: When you installed vs did you install all the C# stuff? You may need to go back and do that. What type of app did you tell vs to create?

Comment: I have the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel. Do I have to uninstall then install again?

Comment: No just run Visual studio setup and add C# part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to Tools --> Options --> Text Editor
2. Click the 'Show All Settings' check box
3. Click 'All Languages'
4. Make sure your settings look like this:

[image]

If that doesn't work, I will delete my answer :)

Comment: Done. Sorry, new around here.

Comment: Not a problem at all. Glad to help.

Comment: Thank you for this screenshot!  I finally know where to find the 'Line numbers' option!